# Has one and has many of itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user instance that has many invitees but only one inviter.
I am trying to access the inviter instance associated with that user and also his invitees.

i.e:

```
user.inviter #=> return another user instance.
user.invitees #=> return a collection on user instances
```

*User.rb*

```
class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :inviter, class_name: Invitation, foreign_key: :invitee_id
  has_many :invitees, class_name: Invitation, foreign_key: :inviter_id
end
```

*Invitation.rb*

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: User, foreign_key: :inviter_id
  belongs_to :invitee, class_name: User, foreign_key: :invitee_id
end
```

migration

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :inviter, references: :user, index: true
      t.references :invitee, references: :user, index: true
      t.foreign_key :users, column: :inviter_id
      t.foreign_key :users, column: :invitee_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This works half of the way because if I call `user.inviter` on a user that has an inviter it will return the invitation instance but not the user like I would like. Same for `user.invitees` returns a collection on invitation instances.

Do y'all have an idea of how to make it work ?

Comment: can you provide the code for `inviter` and `invitee` models?

Comment: there is no inviter invitee model.  `inviter` references another `user` through the invitation model

Answer (score 0):

Your should use [through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) option like this:

```
class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invitation, inverse_of: :inviter
  has_one :inviter, through: :invitation
  has_many :invitations, inverse_of: :invitee
  has_many :invitees, through: :invitations
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: User, inverse_of: :invitation
  belongs_to :invitee, class_name: User, inverse_of: :invitations
end
```

Comment: `has_one :invitation` ? And why the foreign key to `inviter_id` on the has_many ?

Comment: `user.inviter` works and returns the user who invited him. however `user.invitees` return a collection of `invitation` instances instead of ``users

Answer (score 0):

**user.invitees** will give collection of invitation records.
Using **IN** query into User model with all invitee_id which reference to user model will give you collection of users.

```
user_ids = user.invitees.map(&:invitee_id)
User.where(id: user_ids)
```